# parsing xml data return empty value in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

i'm trying to parse data in xml with simple_load_string function in php and it's return an empty data in the $parsed (data parsed) .

the data to parse is like :

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas="http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas">
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>yassine458</cas:user>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

is that possible to parse data with this format or there is another method to do it .

this is my code :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$parsed= simplexml_load_string($result);
```

i'm trying to convert it to json format

Comment: Show us the code as well as the data

Comment: you can take a look

Comment: is there  a solution or not ?

Comment: That is not valid XML so it is difficult to say any more than that as I cannot test it

Comment: i can get that there is not solution to parse it ?

Comment: this is not making any sense xml is valid as i can see

Answer (score 1):

When i was working with xml i am facing the same issue but i found this solution and it worked for me

Documentation :- https://github.com/rentpost/xml2array

OR

https://packagist.org/packages/verdant/xml2array

Use

```
    $xml = '<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas="http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas">
        <cas:authenticationSuccess>
            <cas:user>yassine458</cas:user>
        </cas:authenticationSuccess>
    </cas:serviceResponse>';

    $xml2array = XML2Array::createArray($xml);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml2array);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Accessing "user"

```
    echo $xml2array['cas:serviceResponse']['cas:authenticationSuccess']['cas:user'];
```

Result : -

```
    Array
    (
        [cas:serviceResponse] => Array
            (
                [cas:authenticationSuccess] => Array
                    (
                        [cas:user] => yassine458
                    )

            )

    )
```

if you don't want `cas:` just replace it with "" in xml;

Tested [sendbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f71f19f8c981c3cd8b0b6b1db7dda28beca42c01)

Comment: how could you get the variable cas:user ?

Comment: as you can see i have shown how to access the property it just an array use as array

Comment: XML2Array is not found when i try to make your code

Comment: you have to copy this [https://github.com/rentpost/xml2array/blob/master/Verdant/XML2Array.php] code and make a file with name of XML2Array.php then include this file and it will work

Comment: Answer Updated have a look or just sendbox [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f71f19f8c981c3cd8b0b6b1db7dda28beca42c01]

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents('/path');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Then you can use *$json* or *$array* as you want.

Answer (score 0):

i find this solution :

```
$todelete="xmlns:cas=\"http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas\"";

        $result="<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas=\"http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas\">
                    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
                     <cas:user>pdurant2</cas:user>
                      </cas:authenticationSuccess>
                        </cas:serviceResponse>";
        if (strpos($result, $todelete) !== false) {
            $result= str_replace($todelete,null,$result);
        }
        if (strpos($result, "cas:") !== false) {
            $result= str_replace("cas:",null,$result);

        }
        if (strpos($result, "/cas:") !== false) {
            $result= str_replace("/cas:",null,$result);

        }
        $parsed=simplexml_load_string($result);
```

and it's work for me .